# what's the Ethereum n

Tags: go-ethereum

Ethereum Derivation path(m'/44'/60'/0/'0/n)

when we create ethereum HD wallet through a mnemonic phrase, we always need derivation path. is it fix for a particular currency or we can put whatever we like (ex- m/0/n, m/4/3/n or anything else)?

Answer (score 0):

[BIP-0044](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) gives the following interpretation of derivation path

```
m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / change / address_index
```

- Purpose: Purpose is a constant set to 44'. It indicates that the subtree of this node is used according to BIP0044.
- Coin type: Coin type is a constant, set for each cryptocoin.
- Account: Accounts are numbered from index 0 in sequentially increasing manner.
- Change: Constant 0 is used for external chain and constant 1 for internal chain (also known as change addresses).
- Index: Addresses are numbered from index 0 in sequentially increasing manner.

Answer (score 0):

usually most part of it is the same for different wallets that derive from mnemonic phrase except index:

- Ethereum :

  - index 0 : m/44'/60'/0'/0/0
  - index 1 : m/44'/60'/0'/0/1
- Tron:

  - index 0 : m/44'/197'/0'/0/0
  - index 1 : m/44'/197'/0'/0/1

most wallets display index 0 by default and some others that allow you to create more wallets (like Metamask ) sequentially display next index for you as new wallet